# Ruby/Rails update model attribute with array items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to populate column_name with items from @enc. Problem is #update_all updates all fields with last item in array?

Last item is "MPq3KSzDzLvTeYh+h00HD+5FAgKoNksykJhzROVZWbIJ36WNoBgkSoicJ5wx\nog0g\n".

I am trying to populate with all items from array not just last.
I hope question is clear?
I tried #update_attributes, but no success?
Help.
Thanks

```
@enc=["hUt7ocoih//kFpgEizBowBAdxqqbGV1jkKVipVJwJnPGoPtTN16ZAJvW9tsi\n3inn\n", "wGNyaoEZ09jSg+/IclWFGAXzwz5lXLxJTUKqCFIiOy3ZXRgdwFUsNf/75R2V\nZm83\n", "MPq3KSzDzLvTeYh+h00HD+5FAgKoNksykJhzROVZWbIJ36WNoBgkSoicJ5wx\nog0g\n"]

@enc.each do |i|
PaymentMethod.update_all(enc_number: i)
end
```

Comment: Could you replace `Model` and `column_name` with your actual model and column names?

Comment: @ashwinkumar I am using rails 3.2 so using update_attributes gives error: undefined method

Comment: @Stefan I dont get what u mean?

Comment: Your model probably isn't called `Model` and `column_name` isn't the actual column's name

Comment: @Stefan I just didnt see how that would help?

Comment: Can you be more clear with your requirement. What do you want to do @enc with your model??

Comment: @ashwinkumar I just want to update every field of column name enc_number with the actual items from my array?

Comment: @user3566065 thanks, so what would `enc_number` look like after the assignment?

Comment: @Stefan every field would match every item from array.

Comment: @user3566065 what do you mean by "every field"? `enc_number` looks like a single attribute, how can it contain multiple fields?

Comment: @Stefan from mysql perspective "enc_number" is a column that has many fields. Hope that's clearer.

Comment: The array contains 3 Strings. Which String map to which record in database? If your db has 10 records, how is the mapping then?

Comment: what column type does `enc_number` have in your database?

Comment: i tink i need to take screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  PaymentMethod.all.each_with_index do |payment, n = 0|
   payment.update_column(:enc_number, @enc[n])
   n +=1
  end
```

Comment: I think this code is working but not updating to database? How do I update results to database?

Comment: What do you mean not updating? and code is working? Is it not updating the fields? Try this "payment.update_attributes(enc_number: @enc[n])"

Comment: no sorry it just selects all from PaymentMethod..thats it..even with "payment.update_attributes(enc_number: @enc[n])" Thanks 4 trying

Comment: try removing statement "next unless @env.size < n"

Comment: Yes it did removing "next unless @env.size < n" was the one! Thanks alot m8!!